# Undefined delay issue of ipad views animation

Tags: ipad, ios6, delay, catransition, catransaction

I have an issue with the following code. When I execute it, There is a **undefined delay** withing first `[CATransaction commit]` and `CompletionBlock:`. No idea what is happening there. This only happen when the app run on the device.

This is the time log,

```
2013-04-22 15:59:50.893 MyApp[27038:907] ***** A   
2013-04-22 **15:59:50.894** MyApp[27038:907] ***** B  
2013-04-22 **15:59:53.161** MyApp[27038:907] ***** C  
2013-04-22 15:59:53.162 MyApp[27038:907] ***** D  
2013-04-22 15:59:53.164 MyApp[27038:907] ***** E  
2013-04-22 15:59:53.967 MyApp[27038:907] ***** F
```

-

```
NSLog(@"***** A");

[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{

    [CATransaction begin];

    NSLog(@"***** D");

    for (UIView *view in [masterTableView subviews])
    {
        if (view.tag == 501)
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }

    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:masterTableView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:detailView];

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setDuration:.8];
    [animation setSubtype:transitionFromRight?kCATransitionFromRight:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{

        NSLog(@"***** F");

        for (UIView *view in [detailView subviews])
        {
            if (view.tag == 502)
            {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
                break;
            }
        }

        [self addDetailView];

        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:detailView];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:masterTableView];

        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setDuration:.8];
        [animation setSubtype:transitionFromRight?kCATransitionFromRight:kCATransitionFromLeft];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

        [[detailView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transition"];
    }];

    [[masterTableView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transition"];

    NSLog(@"***** E");
}];

[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{

    NSLog(@"***** C");

    for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews])
    {
        if (view.tag == 500)
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setDuration:0];
    [animation setSubtype:transitionFromRight?kCATransitionFromRight:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [[dummyView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transition"];
}];

[CATransaction commit];

[CATransaction commit];

NSLog(@"***** B");
```

Have I mistaken some thing ?? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As I realized CATransaction creates snap shots of the views which I animate. So it gets some time for that task and some delay occur because of that.

So as a solution now I'm animating a UIImageView with the snap shot image of the view. So now the undefined issue was fixed.